# Deezer API documentation missing

Tags: android, api, sdk, deezer

Hi currently I´m developing an application which is using the Deezer Android SDK. I finally managed to play 30 sec. samples in my application by using the basic player instead of the TrackPlayer.

First I tried to use the TrackPlayer and called the method:

```
TrackPlayer.playTrack(trackid);
```

But this player just produces exceptions:

```
InvalidStreamTokenException
```

So after a while I found the API call:

```
new DefaultPlayerFactory(...).createPlayer();
player.init(trackid, stream_or_sample_uri);
player.play();
```

So now I try to play the full title but even if I create a temporary new premium account the stream-token just produces strange errors... **(State change from RELEASED to INITIALIZING not allowed)** Even the fact how I could check the status of the current user is not clear...

I found some url´s on the page:

http://api.deezer.com/options/  --> Parameter: streaming = true

http://api.deezer.com/user/me --> Parameter: status = 2 (Premium+) / 0 (Free)

But I have not found a function in the android SDK. Maybe it´s missing?

Any support would be great!

Thanks in advance

Edit:

Requested Code:

```
public void login() {
    // Check if a session was stored and request login if not
    if(!m_SessionStore.restore(m_DeezerConnect, m_Activity.getApplication())) {
        String[] permissions = new String[]{
                Permissions.BASIC_ACCESS,
                Permissions.MANAGE_LIBRARY,
                Permissions.LISTENING_HISTORY,
                Permissions.OFFLINE_ACCESS,
        };

        DeezerDialogListener ddl = new DeezerDialogListener();
        m_DeezerConnect.authorize(m_Activity, permissions, ddl);
    } else {
        notifyLoginSuccess();
        loadUserPlaylists();
    }
}

private class DeezerDialogListener implements DialogListener {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle bundle) {
        m_SessionStore.save(m_DeezerConnect, m_Activity.getApplication());

        notifyLoginSuccess();
        loadUserPlaylists();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        notifyLoginError();
    }

    @Override
    public void onException(Exception e) {
        notifyLoginError();
    }
}

private void loadUserPlaylists() {
    try {
        // First try
        //m_DeezerPlayer = new TrackPlayer(m_Activity.getApplication(), m_DeezerConnect, new WifiAndMobileNetworkStateChecker());

        m_DeezerPlayer = new DefaultPlayerFactory(m_Activity.getApplication(), m_DeezerConnect, new WifiAndMobileNetworkStateChecker()).createPlayer();
        m_DeezerPlayer.addOnPlayerErrorListener(this);
        m_DeezerPlayer.addOnPlayerProgressListener(this);
        m_DeezerPlayer.addOnPlayerStateChangeListener(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    AlbumsListener al = new AlbumsListener();
    DeezerRequest ar = DeezerRequestFactory.requestCurrentUserAlbums();
    ar.setId("ar");
    m_DeezerConnect.requestAsync(ar, al);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of how you init your TrackPlayer / BasicPlayer ? As well as how you handle authentication ?

Answer (score 1):

The *InvalidTokenException* was an issue we had when using the Android SDK in the emulator.
It was fixed in SDK version v0.10.19 and upper available here: [Android SDK](http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/android)